# What was the first memory given to Jonas in The Giver?

Tags: the-giver

In the book [*The Giver*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giver) by [Lois Lowry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lois_Lowry), the Giver hands down memories to Jonas, a 12 year old.  What was the first memory the Giver gave to Jonas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From *The Giver* - very last paragraph of chapter 10:

"'I'm going to give you the memory of snow,' the old man said, and placed his hands on Jonas' bare back."

Answer (score 4):

In "The Giver," Jonas' first memory is about the snow. The snow teaches him about the hill and the sled. The snow formed a hill for Jonas to go sledding on.

Answer (score 2):

The first memory Jonas received was the memory about someone sledding down a hill that was covered in snow. He had felt the feeling the exhilaration of movement and speed even though he has never felt snow or strong wind or even a hill. The wind had kept his face really cold as he went down the hill, his speed growing.